# docker swarm custom containers with traefik

Tags: express, ubuntu, microservices, docker-swarm, traefik

I'm trying to set up a docker swarm using traefik in digital ocean. I followed [this tutorial](https://originmaster.com/traefik-docker-swarm-and-subdomains-4aaaeca9222d) and I get it to work entirely until I add one of my custom made containers. I am trying to simply add one first (there are 14 in total) and they are all very very similar, all of them are express apps that serve as restful API's handling one resource per service. However, when trying to access that specific subdomain I get a connection refused  error.

Here's my docker-stack.yml file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    networks:
      - mynet
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command: --api

  main:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - mynet
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.backend=main"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.com"

  two:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    networks:
      - mynet
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=8000"
        - "traefik.backend=two"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:two.domain.com"

  three:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    networks:
      - mynet
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.backend=three"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:three.domain.com"

  user-service:
    image: hollarves/users:latest
    env_file:
      - .env.user
    networks: 
      - mynet
    deploy:
      labels:
        - "traefik.port=80"
        - "traefik.backend=users"
        - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:users.domain.com"              

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: overlay
```

As I said, going to two.domain.com and three.domain.com works fine, and the whoami containers respond with their info. However, I get a connection refused error when trying users.domain.com

Note: domain.com is an actual domain I am using that is live pointing to a digitalocean cluster, I'm just hiding it for privacy reasons.

The entrypoint for this users-service is:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    require("dotenv").load()
}

const express = require("express"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    logger = require("morgan"),
    //helmet = require("helmet"),
    cors = require("cors"),
    PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 80

const server = express(),
    routes = require("./server/routes")


//server.use(helmet())
server.use(cors())
server.use(logger("dev"))
server.use(bodyParser.json())
server.use("/", routes)

/*eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["log"] }] */
const serverObj = server.listen(PORT, () => { console.log("Server listening in PORT ", PORT) })

module.exports = serverObj
```

I can also confirm that this service is listening on PORT 80 as that's what it outputs when fetching logs from it using `docker service logs test-stack_user-service`:

```
test-stack_user-service.1.35p3lxzovphr@node-2    | > users-mueve@0.0.1 start /usr/src/app
test-stack_user-service.1.35p3lxzovphr@node-2    | > node server.js
test-stack_user-service.1.35p3lxzovphr@node-2    | 
test-stack_user-service.1.35p3lxzovphr@node-2    | Server listening in PORT  80
```

Here is my traefik.toml config file just in case:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
[retry]
[docker]
endpoint="unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
exposedByDefault=true
watch=true
swarmmode=true
```

I can also see the containers in the traefik dashboard like I used to in my local environment.

I feel like I'm missing a very small detail that is preventing my service from working correctly. Any pointers will be extremely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your DNS records are up to date and the request gets to your server?

Comment: Hi Andrey. Yes, request are getting to my server on two.domain.com and three.domain.com which are simple whoami containers. It's just my express container that is getting a connection refused error. I'm quite lost with this because this is my first time using docker swarm, apart from very simple tutorials I've done in the past.

Comment: I mean maybe only your users.domain.com points to some other server and other domains are correct? Seems like your request can't get to the server, because everything you've posted looks correct to me.
Could you temporarily try exposing your service on three.domain.com for example and check whether it works?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it was quite late here. I just tried what you said and now my custom container actually works. Also, the whoami container that used to work in three.domain.com now won't work on users.domain.com. So I think itś safe to say it's a problem with the subdomain "users", although I don't understand how the word "users" is affecting the outcome.

Comment: Check out the records on your DNS server, probably something is wrong there.